# Run two activities parallely

Tags: android, gps

Im developing android application to detect the ongoing traffic condition using accelerometer and update the data in a data base. the location of the traffic condition s obtained by using gps. I have developed the algorthm to detect traffic.after detecting  want to turn on gps and send the data to data base. does it need to do the gps thing in a seperate activity? if so then how can i run the two actvtes parallely(as i have to detect traffic while gps location s obtaining and that actvity should work continuously)
plz help me m realy confused
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please look into android services. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

The Gps detection would be in a service and run separately from your app but in a bound service and send callbacks to your activity of GPS coordinates.

Comment: thanks for quick responce.can i run both traffic detection and gps from service